# Angular 6: downloading file issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I faced with a problem and I can't find any solution for it. So I apologize in advance if this question somehow duplicates someone else.

The problem is I'm sending `GET` request to backend and have a response. There is `Blob` inside responses body. I trying to download it but before I'm getting a filename to name my downloading file. And locally  everything works good. But in external version file won't downloading. I have response after clicking on a button and I saw that I went into the save function in `FileUtil`. But downloading doesn't start. Could anybody knows whats the problem is?

Here is the response in Network tab in Chrome inspect tool (as you can see all headers are receiving)
[image]

**download.service.ts**

```
downloadFile(id: string) {
    return this.apiService.getFile(id).pipe(
        map(response => {
            const data = response.body;
            const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/zip' });
            FileUtil.save(blob, this.getFileName(response.headers));
        })
    )
}

private getFileName(headers: HttpHeaders) {
    const contentDisposition = headers.get('Content-Disposition') || '';
    const matches = /filename=([^;]+)/ig.exec(contentDisposition);
    const fileName = (matches[1] || 'file.zip').trim();
    return fileName;
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
getFile(id: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(requestUrl, {responseType: 'blob' as 'json', observe: 'response'});
}
```

**FileUtil.ts**

```
static save(data: Blob, name: string) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    a.href = url;
    const filename = name;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284400/download-a-file-using-angular-6-and-spring-rest-api/53285289#53285289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of problem was missing `('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Disposition')` and browser didn't know that my response was the attachment that he should download. So check the headers of your response twice.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

**FileUtil.ts**

```
 save(data: Blob, name: string) {
   const a = document.createElement('a');
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'octet/stream' });
   const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
   a.href = url;
   a.download = "filename.csv"; // you need to write the extension of file here
   a.click();
   window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  })
 }
```